# Unable to animate seach bar with Jquery animate

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Im trying get this animation to cause the bar to expand 90% window width then recede when empty.

It should recede when clicked out side of bar and expand when clicked inside

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Implementar procurar YouTube</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script_fancy.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Procura<span>Video</span></h1>
                <p>Procura YouTube</p>
            </header>
            <section>
                <form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return search()">
                    <div class="fieldcontainer">
                        <input type="search" id="query" class="search-field" placeholder="Search YouTube...">
                        <input type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search-btn" value="">
                    </div>
                </form>

                <ul id="results"></ul>
                <div id="buttons"></div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, DAW  </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html
```

>

This is my JS

```
// Searchbar Handler
$(function(){
    var searchField = $('#query');
    var icon = $('#search-btn');

    // Evento focus barra
    $(searchField).on('focus', function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width:'100%'
        },400);
        $(icon).animate({
            right: '10px'
        }, 400);
    });

  // handler para blur. A animação apena occore se o campo ainda não tiver texto
    $(searchField).on('blur', function(){
        if(searchField.val() == ''){
            $(searchField).animate({
                width:'45%'
            },400, function(){});
            $(icon).animate({
                right:'360px'
            },400, function(){});
        }
    });
  //evitar que o form seja submetido da forma tradicional, para um server
    $('#search-form').submit(function(e){ //passar a função para não submeter
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/ayatullahrahmani/vp3c7zpt/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another useless use of jQuery. Here's a solution with 7 lines of CSS.

```css
#query {
  width: 30%;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

#query:focus {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Implementar procurar YouTube</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script_fancy.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Procura<span>Video</span></h1>
                <p>Procura YouTube</p>
            </header>
            <section>
                <form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return search()">
                    <div class="fieldcontainer">
                        <input type="search" id="query" class="search-field" placeholder="Search YouTube...">
                        <input type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search-btn" value="">
                    </div>
                </form>

                <ul id="results"></ul>
                <div id="buttons"></div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, DAW  </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```